# Sum the values of a cell in Excel or change to a different expression of that value in another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, formula

I have a cell of a worksheet with a value of

1h 25m

entered with the cell (got it from a Jira import). I am trying to figure out how to populate another cell on the same row with a purely numerical version of this cell value, i.e.

85

This is so that I can run SUMIF statements to get the total amounts of minutes for a given person, on a given day.
[image]

As in the provided image, I want the sum total amount of Log Work (Column C) for Matthew R. on the 17th of October.

Comment: Use a helper column and test for "h" use left() to get hours * 60 then find the minutes value and add.

Comment: @Rackman, please verify your Jira output or the process you use to export to Excel, I tested with my Jira instance for the field: **Time Spent** and **Remaining Estimate** (I don't have **Log.Work** in my instance) that is represented in Jira issue search as `10 minutes`, but when I export the result to Excel on a given column I am getting `600` which is the corresponding values in seconds. Check if you are exporting the information properly. Usually there is no need to make such conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we're creating two helper columns. You could combine everything, but thought this may be easier to illustrate.

| Value | hours | minutes | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5m | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 1h 35m | 1 | 35 | 95 |
| 3h | 3 | 0 | 180 |
| 4h 55m | 4 | 55 | 295 |
| 12h | 12 | 0 | 720 |

Column A (Value) is your original value.

Column B (hours) is the following formula, which finds the letter "h" and returns everything to the left of it. If H is not found then return a 0.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("h",A2)-1),0)
```

Column C (minutes) is the following formula, which returns everything to the right of "h" and then removes "m" and trims it. But if "m" is not found then return a 0.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",A2)),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("h",A2)),A2),"m","")),0)
```

Lastly, column D simply calculates total minutes as:

```
=(B2*60)+C2
```

You can probably shorten column C's formula, but this at least provides you an interim solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Isolated! I compressed the statement to be

=IFERROR(LEFT($C2,FIND("h",$C2)-1),0)*60+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",$C2)),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(RIGHT($C2,LEN($C2)-FIND("h",$C2)),$C2),"m","")),0)

and that is working like a charm!!